# Yii2 dataprovider- exclude first 2 elements

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

How can i exclude first 2 elements in dataprovider and get other elemets by every 3?

```
1  2   3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 10 12 13 14
x x  |      |     |      |        |
```

I need such results

```
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 0 10
12 13 14
```

Comment: you question is nor clear .. explain better please

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all models form existing dataprovider, then filter items using PHP as you want, then make new data provider from these items using [ArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html).

For example:

```
// Some prepared data provider
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
$dataProvider->query
    ->orderBy(['created_at' => SORT_DESC]);


// Retrieving all models
$allModels = $dataProvider->getModels();


// Some manipulations with $allModels array
// ...


// Preparing new data provider from modified array of models
$dataProvider            = new ArrayDataProvider();
$dataProvider->allModels = $allModels;
$dataProvider->key       = 'id';
$dataProvider->pagination->setPageSize($maxRows);
```